# Getting the Full Azure AD UserID for a local User

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, intune

I'm trying to answer what I hope is a simple question. I have a device enrolled in AzureAD and autopiloted. Using the IntuneManagementExtenstion I'd like to acquire the FULL user name of the user currently logged in to use elsewhere in scripts. I cannot see a way of doing it.

All the example I can find return either the short name, or the AzureAD domain and the user name for example:

Tenant is **mytestdomain.onmicrosoft.com**
User is **mytestuser@mytestdomain.com**

most methods if you just google or search stackoverflow will return either:

**AzureAD\mytestuser**
or
**mytestuser**

I need one that returns the full **mytestuser@mytestdomain.com**. This is because the tenant has several vanity names so I need to determine which one is logged in (for example **mytestuser@mytestdomain.com** is a different user account to **mytestuser@mytestdomain2.com** or **mytestuser@mytestdomain3.com**). Therefore, I can't just append my tenant name on the end of the output other methods.

Any thoughts appreciated. Methods that require installation of msol/azuread modules don't seem to work as they require user login, which defeats the point, and as it's being run by the intune management extension, the user can't interact anyway.

Thanks

Comment: where is your code? how can we reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little busy to test this right now, but it should do the trick.

You can have Intune run a Powershell script. This command will return the full user account name in the format you've described.

```
whoami.exe /UPN
```

Since you've stated you want the user who is logged in already. When you are configuring the settings in Intune, make sure to select the option to "Run this script using the logged on credentials".

Answer (score 0):

This line will return UPN from domain join info in registry.
Must be run with admin priveleges

```
[string]$($1='Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\CloudDomainJoin\JoinInfo\';if(Test-Path -Path $1){(Get-ItemProperty -Path ('{0}\{1}' -f ($1,(Get-ChildItem -Path $1).Name.Split('\')[-1])) -Name 'UserEmail' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'UserEmail')}else{''})
```